# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First - How to map a string containing csv of Entity ID's (foreign keys) to the corresponding Entity

Tags: mapping, entity-framework-4.1, database-first

Before I submit my question, please be aware that I'm working with an existing database owned by a third party vendor, so unfortunately changing the database format is not an option.

Here's the issue: I have an Entity mapped to a database table that has a varchar column that contains one to many foreign keys in csv format. Those foreign keys correspond to the ID's of another Entity type. What I've been doing is writing a function that creates a List of ID's from that csv list and then I search for that Entity through the DBContect object. What I'd like to do is map a relationship between the entities. Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do that without changes in the database. EF is ORM tool but it is still very dependent on correctness of database design. Storing multiple values in single column is breaking even [first database normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). For EF your column containing csv data is single string value and you cannot make relation on that value.

Btw. it is even more complicated because the column cannot represent one-to-many relation in standard relational meaning - that would require dependent entities to contain Id of your master entity, not that master entity contains Ids of all dependent entities.